# Spring Security : request mapped to /error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Security. Request `TRACE http://localhost:8080/invalid/path` gets mapped `/error` in my spring boot application. Can I know where exactly this request gets mapped to `/error`. I want to handle the request to send custom response. I enabled the debugging for web security by the following line.

```
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }
```

- Output of `curl -D - -X TRACE http://localhost:8081/invalid/path`

```
HTTP/1.1 405
Allow: HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Content-Type: message/http
Content-Length: 83
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 06:24:25 GMT

TRACE /error HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:8104
user-agent: curl/7.64.1
accept: */*
```

The application log shows the following

```
************************************************************

Request received for TRACE '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@7dba82cf

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8104
user-agent: curl/7.64.1
accept: */*


Security filter chain: [] empty (bypassed by security='none') 


************************************************************
```

My Custom Firewall ignores the `RequestRejectedException`

```
@Override
public FirewalledRequest getFirewalledRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
 try {
  return super.getFirewalledRequest(request);
 } catch (RequestRejectedException ex) {
  return new FirewalledRequest(request) {
   @Override
   public void reset() {}
  };
 }
}
```

Any help on this ?

Using Spring Boot 2.2.6

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when you have `server.context-path` only? Spring web tried to redirect to `/error` path when an error occurred, but `spring-security` denied it. It is supposed to be a bug because the correct path should be `/context-path/error`, right? There are 2 options that can solve this

1. By allowing `/error` in webSecurityConfig

```
@Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/error");
  }
```

2. Tell spring to allow forwarding `X-Forwarded-Prefix` by add this to `application.property` file

```
server.forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

Comment: It appears that this allows requests under /error, in a wildcard fashion. Are there any security concerns with this solution?